# DropdownButtonFormField causing RenderFlex Overflow

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error when I try to put 2 dropdown buttons on a form side by side. Please kindly help.

The relevant error-causing widget was
DropdownButtonFormField
lib\signup\signupBasicDetails.dart:947
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis. horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

```
Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 90,
              width: 100,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "Province",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat Regular", fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Theme(
                      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                        canvasColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            provinceDropdown = newValue;
                            provinceController.text = provinceDropdown;
                            cityListSetUp();
                          });
                        },
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == "Select Province") {
                            return 'Please select province!';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        isDense: false,
                        value: provinceDropdown,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 15),
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                const Radius.circular(4),
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 1, color: Color(0xff2E2E2E))),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 1, color: Color(0xffDEDEDE))),
                            fillColor: Colors.white70),
                        selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return province.map((String value) {
                            return Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(provinceDropdown,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "Montserrat Regular",
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      color: Colors.black)),
                            );
                          }).toList();
                        },
                        items: province
                            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: Text(value,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "Montserrat Regular",
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    color: sankaraGreyColor)),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 90,
              width: 100,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "City",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Montserrat Regular", fontSize: 14),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Theme(
                      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                        canvasColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                        onChanged: (String newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            //cityListSetUp();
                            cityDropdown = newValue;
                            cityController.text = cityDropdown;
                          });
                        },
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == "Select City") {
                            return 'Please select city!';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        isDense: false,
                        value: cityDropdown,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding:
                                EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 15),
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                const Radius.circular(4),
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 1, color: Color(0xff2E2E2E))),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    width: 1, color: Color(0xffDEDEDE))),
                            fillColor: Colors.white70),
                        selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return city.map((String value) {
                            return Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              child: Text(cityDropdown,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: "Montserrat Regular",
                                      fontSize: 12,
                                      color: Colors.black)),
                            );
                          }).toList();
                        },
                        items: city
                            .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: Text(value,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: "Montserrat Regular",
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                    color: sankaraGreyColor)),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
```

Comment: You can try wrapping both Top Containers with expanded!

Comment: @KrishBhanushali tried that no luck. any other route i could take?